# Searching multiple values in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, search, filter

I have a problem:

Let's say I have a table with songs. The table includes "Back in Black" by AC/DC in it, and I have the chords too, which would be "E, D, A, B, G".

I want to be able to search things like "Back AC/DC" or "Back in Black G" or "AC/DC E A" or things like that. I mean, multiple values within the same song.

The code is the following:

search.component.ts:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-hero">
    Buscar material:
    <br>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="enteredSearchValue" placeholder="Sin tildes ni espacios aún, y en minúscula"
      (input)="onSearchTextChanged()">
  </div>
</div>
```

search.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-hero">
    Buscar material:
    <br>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="enteredSearchValue" placeholder="Sin tildes ni espacios aún, y en minúscula"
      (input)="onSearchTextChanged()">
  </div>
</div>
```

home.component.ts:

```
searchText: string = ''

  onSearchTextEntered(searchValue: string){
    this.searchText = searchValue;
  }
```

home.component.html:

```
<app-search (searchTextChanged)="onSearchTextEntered($event)"></app-search>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" routerLink="/nuevacn" *ngIf="isLogged" style="float: right; margin-top: -38px; margin-right: 122px;">
    Agregar Cancion
</button>

<div class="row" id="coso">
    <div class="col lg 1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Canción</th>
                    <th>Artista</th>
                    <th>Instrumento</th>
                    <th>Acordes</th>
                    <th>Técnica</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Dificultad</th>
                    <th>Género</th>
                    <th>Modo</th>
                    <th>Observaciones</th>
                </tr>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let Cancion of cn">
                    <tr *ngIf="searchText === '' || Cancion.nameC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) 
                                               || Cancion.artistC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.instrumentC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.chordsC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.techniqueC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.typeC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.difficultyC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.genreC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.scaleC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                                               || Cancion.observationsC.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())">
                        <td>{{Cancion.nameC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.artistC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.instrumentC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.chordsC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.techniqueC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.typeC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.difficultyC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.genreC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.scaleC}}</td>
                        <td>{{Cancion.observationsC}}</td>
                        <td *ngIf="isLogged">
                            <button class="btn btn-light" routerLink="/editcn/{{Cancion.id}}">
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill"></i> EDITAR</button>
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="isLogged">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete(Cancion.id)">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> BORRAR</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
</div>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfcGN.jpg)

How could I do what i just asked?

I tried to be able to search multiple values in my Angular project.

Comment: are you getting this data from a service/http call? and does that service not support filtering?

Comment: I'm getting this data from a service with HttpClient, connected to a Spring Boot Back-end